# Object assign to update object's nested object

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a list of objects. I want to create a new instance of these objects to update one value.

```js
const arr = [
  { data: { name: "first", type: "child" } },
  { data: { name: "second", type: "parent" } },
];
```

I would like to have an array of the same objects, but whose type would be upper case like below:

```js
const arr = [
  { data: { name: "first", type: "CHILD" } },
  { data: { name: "second", type: "PARENT" } },
];
```

I map this array and return new mapped objects, I can add new prop to an object but I can not find a way to change data.type.
Here is my piece of code:

```js
const a = arr.map(e => {
    return Object.assign({},e,{data['type']:'???'}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this way?

```js
const arr=[{data:{name:'first',type:'child'}},{data:{name:'second', type:'parent'}}]
const a = arr.map(e => {
  let data = {...e["data"], type: e["data"].type.toUpperCase()};
  return ({...e, data});
});
console.log(a);
```

Comment: with a slight modification it was what I needed, thanks;)

Answer (score 3):

Using `map`:

```
const result = data.map(({ data }) => ({ data: { ...data, type: data.type.toUpperCase() }}));
```

```js
const data = [{data:{name:'first',type:'child'}},{data:{name:'second', type:'parent'}}]

const result = data.map(({ data }) => ({ data: { ...data, type: data.type.toUpperCase() }}));

console.log({result})
```

Comment: Please check the input/output again

Comment: The objects are supposed to have a `data` property

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use Object.assign:

```js
const arr = [
  { data: { name: "first", type: "child" } },
  { data: { name: "second", type: "parent" } },
];

const a = arr.map(e => ({
    data: {
       name: e.data.name,
       type: e.data.type.toUpperCase()
    }
}))

console.log(a)
```

Comment: I use object assign because i'm adding some new values to them

Comment: map will return new objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: yes and I want new array of objects with 'modified' values. Of course original array has to stay untouched

Comment: That's the purpose of `map`. It does exactly what you want to do. Try my code

Comment: This code will never work. Try to run and you will got `TypeError: e.type is undefined`

Comment: You are right, my bad! I've modified my answer